# Реализация команды top в Linux на языке C

Tags: linux, c

Всем привет, хочу реализовать команду top, но только для 1 процесса, вся инфа о процессе хранится в файле /proc/[pid]/status. Не понимаю какие строчки считывать из этого файла. Хочу чтобы были считанны или как преобразованы эти данные к виду: ЦП n%, Память m MiB. Почитал на сайтах про этот файл, но как бы не могу вычленить, что мне нужгл

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Хочу чтобы были считанны или как преобразованы эти данные к виду:  ЦП n%,

Для этого из `/proc/[pid]/stat` надо получить `utime` и `stime` процесса, сложить их, подождать какое-то время (полсекунды—секунду) и снова прочитать `utime` и `stime`. Затем разделить разницу первого и второго времени на то время которое прождал между измерениями, а результат умнож на 100 — получишь число в процентах. `utime` и `stime` хранятся в тиках (см. `sysconf(_SC_CLK_TCK)`).

> Память m MiB.

Зависит от того, какая именно память тебе нужна. Обычный `top` выводит 3 вида: `virt`, `res` и `shr`. Все они есть в ``/proc/[pid]/statmem`и в`/proc/[pid]/status`:

- *Виртуальная* (`virt`) — это `size` и `VmSize` в `statmem` и `status` соответственно.
- *Резидентная* (`res`) — это `resident` и `VmRSS` в `statmem` и `status`.
- *Разделяемая* (`shr`) — это `shared` и `RssFile+RssShmem` в `statmem` и `status`.

В чём разница между ними смотри в любом руководстве по unix-подобным ОС. Тебя скорей всего будет интересовать резидентная. В `statmem` размеры памяти хранятся в страницах, запросить размер страницы можно с помощью `sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE)` (почти на всех системах он будет 4096 т.е. 4 kiB ). В `status` всё хранится в килобайтах (нормальных — киБ).

---

Подробности по содержимому файлов смотри в `man 5 proc`.

Comment: файл stat вот такого вида - много много разных числе, но они никак не характерезуются, что с ними делать ?

Comment: @DanBit, в `man 5 proc` смотри... на русском есть в man-pages-ru, но в этих наших интернетах свежей версии нет (на opennet'е тоже русская есть, но сильно старая — информация там релевантна, но пользоваться ей не так удобно)...

Comment: Разобрался спасибо. Эххх хорошую бы книгу по этому всему...

Comment: "Нормальные", то есть двоичные, называются _кибибайты_, а десятичные -- _килобайты_.

Comment: @0andriy к чертям эту МЭК'овскую фантазию... сокращение для них я ещё не против использовать, но полное название — нетушки, спасибо...